# 'Jump forward' to next section in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible in Rails to have code like this?

```
if ...
  skip_to_section_1
end
if ...
  skip_to_section_2
end

...code...
begin_section_1...
begin_section_2...
```

For clarity, the real code structure is considerably more complex than above so just using more `if` statements makes the code uglier and introduces redundancy. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just throw the sections of logic into a couple methods? I assume that if the first `if` evaluates to true, then you want both sections to run. If that was was you intended, then this would be how I would do it:

```
if ...
  section_1
  section_2

if ...
  section_2
end

...other code...

def section_1
  ...
end

def section_2
  ...
end
```